# PHP settings for Building ecommerce site in Joomla

Tags: php, apache, joomla, xampp, virtuemart

I am having problems in installing VirtueMart plugin in Joomla 1.7. I have deployed Joomla on XAMPP in Windows 7.

I have downloaded VirtueMart 1.1.9 (stable [complete package]). When I unzip and try to upload the file "com_...", following error arise:

```
 There was an error uploading this file to the server.
```

I have changed the file size limit to 10 MB and max post size to 30 MB in php.ini but still its not working. Please let me know the necessary settings to get it running.

Comment: Try uploading it per FTP and install directly from that directory

Answer (score 0):

Learn to read the requirements buddy. ;)

```
VirtueMart 1.1.9 is the latest stable version available. 
It is compatible with Joomla! 1.5.x only!
```